# Sequence: If $a>b$ then it exists $n_{0}\in \mathbb N$ such that if $n>n_{0}$ then $x_n>y_{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n,y_n$ two sequences such that $x_{n} \to a$ and $y_{n} \to b$.

If $a>b$ then it exists $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>n_{0}$ then $x_{n}>y_{n}$

Comment: @Peter he has to mention that $n \geq n_0$ in the second line i believe..not $n>n_0$

Comment: @MariosGretsas This makes no difference. If the inequality is true for $n\ge n_0$, it is also true for $n>n_0-1$ and if it is true for $n>n_0$, it is also true for $n\ge n_0+1$

Comment: @Peter yes i had another thing in mind..the O.P has to reverse the inequality..must $x_n>y_n$

Comment: Yes is a sequence, sorry sorry if i had a typo

Comment: @Peter done....

Comment: @MariosGretsas Now the question is OK :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since $x_{n} \to a$ as $n \to \infty$, For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_{1}(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N_{1}(\epsilon)$, $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$.
- Since $y_{n} \to a$ as $n \to \infty$, For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_{2}(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N_{2}(\epsilon)$, $|y_n-b|<\epsilon$.

Take $\epsilon=(a-b)/4$. Then, for all $n>\max\{N_{1}(\epsilon), N_{2}(\epsilon)\}$, we have $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ and $|y_n-b|<\epsilon$. Futhermore, $x_n-a>-\epsilon$ and $y_n-b<\epsilon$. Therefore, for all $n>\max\{N_{1}(\epsilon), N_{2}(\epsilon)\}$, we have
\begin{align*}
x_{n}-y_{n} 
&>(a-\epsilon)-(b+\epsilon) \\
&=(a-b)-2\epsilon \\
&=(a-b)-\frac{a-b}{2} \\
&=\frac{a-b}{2} \\
&>0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Define $d=b-a$.

There's an $n_1$ such that if $n>n_1$ then $$|x_n-a|<\dfrac{d}{2}$$ since $x_n$ converges to $a$. Similarly, There's an $n_2$ such that if $n>n_2$ then $|y_n-b|<\dfrac{d}{2}$ since $y_n$ converges to $b$.
Define $$n_0=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$$ Then if $n>n_0$, then $x_n<y_n$. In the illustration below, the red dots are $x_n$'s for $n>n_1$ and the blue dots are $y_n$'s for $n>n_2$.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't see the image anymore! +)